# How to select multiple values ​in one field?

Tags: python, odoo

How to select multiple values ​​in one field?

```
class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.attribute"

    exclude = fields.Many2many('product.attribute', string='Exclude')
```

In this field I want to select several attributes.
Or need to use One2many ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the relation name manually because the source and destination models are the same:

```
relation='product_attribute_exclude'
```

In this case, `column1` and `column2` are not provided and will be generated automatically and should be equal to `product_attribute_id` which will raise a `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn` error, so you need to provide their names explicitly.

Try the following example:

```
exclude = fields.Many2many('product.attribute', relation='product_attribute_exclude',
                            column1="attribute_id", column2="exclude_id", string='Exclude')
```

*It is enough to provide only one column name different from `product_attribute_id` to fix the `DuplicateColumn` error*

Comment: Kenly, Thank you! It works. 
I will study the documentation about it